# If $|z| = 1, z \in \mathbb{C}$, what can you say about the real and imaginary parts of $z^i$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> If $|z| = 1, z \in \mathbb{C}$, what can you say about the real and imaginary parts of $z^i$?

I am not sure how to approach this question.

I have let $z = re^{i\theta}$ and then using $|z| = 1$, I find $$|re^{i\theta}| = 1\Rightarrow |r| |e^{i\theta}| = 1$$ so $ |r| = 1$.

Then $z^i = r^i e^{-\theta}$, but I don't see how I can proceed using what I know...

Comment: You are neglecting the fact that $r=1$. You have $z = e^{i\theta}$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. But  I am not sure if $1^i$ is still 1... Something might go wrong in the complex plane, I am not sure

Comment: @PhysicsMathsLove. $1^i=e^{ln1^i}=e^{iln1}$

Comment: ah thanks so much!

Comment: This is a bit tricky for me... I did not realize that @imranfat has already posted the key step seconds before me. Well, a comment about this is that, any power of complex values is _defined_ in the sense of exponent-logarithm, i.e., $z_1^{z_2}:=\exp\left(z_2\log z_1\right)$. Specifically, this definition _can't_ be understood as $\log z_1^{z_2}=z_2\log z_1$: Since $\log$ is multivalued, $\log z_1^{z_2}=z_2\log z_1$ does not hold in general (for the principal branch of $\log$).

Comment: How do you suggest to define $$z^w$$ when $z$ and $w$ are complex numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put it as follows.
$$
z^i=e^{i\log z}=e^{i\log\left(re^{i\theta}\right)}=e^{i\left(\log r+i\theta\right)}=e^{i\log r-\theta}.
$$
Provided that $\left|z\right|=1$, we have $r=1$. Thus
$$
z^i=e^{i\log r-\theta}=e^{-\theta}.
$$